# What does this type cast mean?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I saw a piece of code like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
static VOID (WINAPI * pFun) (DWORD seconds) = NULL;

void foo(PVOID * par){
    return;
}

int main(){
    foo(&(PVOID&) pFun); // type-cast 1
    foo((PVOID *) (&pFun)); // type-cast 2
    return 0;
}
```

I can understand the type-cast 2, but how does type-cast 1 work?

Comment: Are you sure that's C not C++?

Comment: @KennyTM I've tagged it C++ now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're using C++.

In `windows.h` `VOID` and `PVOID` are defined as `void` and `void*` respectively.

```
#define VOID void

typedef void *PVOID;
```

Let's look at a basic program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(void** pp)
{
  int i = *((int*) *pp);
  cout << i << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 10;
  int *p = &i;

  foo((void**) &p); // call #1
  foo(&(void*&) p); // call #2
}
```

In the first case, we're taking the address of `p`, which is `int**`, and passing it to `foo()` by casting it to `void**`.

In the second case, we're first casting `p` to `void*&` and then taking its address, which would be `void**`, and passing that to `foo()`. The reason it's `void*&` and not `void*` is that you can use the unary `&` operator (address of) only on an [lvalue](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/).

Comment: So, the effects of the two type-casts are the same, right? Which is more widely used?

Comment: @SetTimer "Depends." I don't know what you're doing with `PVOID` there (ages since I wrote a Windows program), so can't say. All else being equal, the one that's easier to read is the one that should ideally be used more often. We don't live in an ideal world though.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. BTW, I hate such windows-specific type definitions as PVOID and DWORD.

Answer (score 0):

`(PVOID&) pFun` forces the compiler to treat `pFun` as a `PVOID`, and takes its address, effectively passing a `PVOID*` as parameter.

This type of cast `(TYPE&)` interprets the memory as if it represented a `TYPE`.

Also, I know that in C++ you can automatically take the address of the function by writing `foo` instead of `&foo`, not sure if it's supported in pure C.

Comment: @SetTimer usually that means there's no direct cast between pFun and PVOID. With the ampersand, the compiler is told to reinterpret the memory. For example, you can have `std::string x; int k = (int&)x;` whereas `int k = (int)x` would fail.